# Reading the path from a config and delete the files

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to read the files from a path defined in a config file. Then i need to delete certain files which are older than 14 days. I have not written the code for checking the time but finding the files here is failing.

**Code**

```
def cleanup():
global config, logger, status, file_path
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('config.cfg')
for section in sorted(config.sections(), key=str.lower):
    if not config.has_option(section, 'server.user_name'):
        continue
    env.user = config.get(section, 'server.user_name')
    env.password = config.get(section, 'server.password')
    host = config.get(section, 'server.ip')
    file_path= config.get(section, 'server.path')

    print "Trying to connect to {} server.....".format(section)

    with settings(hide('warnings', 'running', 'stdout', 'stderr'),warn_only=True, host_string=host):
        try:
            print "Connected to {} server".format(section)
            for filename in os.listdir(file_path):
                print filename

        except Exception as e:
            print e
            print 'Could not connect to {} server\n'.format(section)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cleanup()
```

**Config**

```
[sync location]
server.ip = 110.109.117.113
server.user_name = root
server.password = 123
server.path = /usr/rosh/test
```

This is the error i am getting.

**Error**

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Users/roradhak/Work/Scripts/YES-tidy/rosh_files_tidy.py
Trying to connect to sync location server.....
Connected to sync location server
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/rosh/test'
Could not connect to sync location server
```

Can someone help me to get the files under the folder set in the config?

Comment: So does `/usr/rosh/test` exist? Usually users' home directories are in `/home`, not `/usr`.

Comment: @Thomas yes, it exists

Comment: @Thomas ... Any idea?

Comment: No, not if that directory really exists and is readable and executable by the user this script runs as.